# Any way to change inbuild memary queue to your own queue?

Tags: java, spring, stomp, sockjs, spring-rabbit

#### My Configuration:

```
configureMessageBroker(final MessageBrokerRegistry config) 
config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
```

Here we are using inbuild memary queue name `/app` and `/topic`. I here any way to change or replace with our own defined queues for meassing.

If there is any way to do. Please explain me how to do. I am new to STOMP meassing.